# Convert string number to float in mongodb and python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a huge data in mongodb database and I want to figure out the data distribution such as min value, max value, average, and so on. My problem is the data type is string instead of integer or float so I can't sort the data, calculate the average etc. 
is there a way to convert datatype from string to float within pipeline? 
For example, to convert string date to date type, there is [$dateFromString(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)

Or any other better idea to solve this problem?

Comment: No such functions are provided in the pipeline. See 
  [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11400) for details. You will need to convert them and save in db with expected types before you can run aggregation.

Comment: Thank you Veeram. Sadly to know that, maybe I should change the data type first.

Answer (score 0):

Since MongoDB is based off of Javascript, iirc, you can use the function 'parseFloat' to try to convert another data type to a float. There is also a 'parseInt' which tries to convert to an integer in case you need that.

Comment: Thank you. But I work on python. is it possible? 
I want to find just min value or max value so I don't want to find all the data then parse them one by one because it would take more time since my data is huge. But I will try if there is no possible way

Comment: In Python, the equivalent function to convert something to float is 'float'. In this case, you will have to parse all of the data to find the min and the max values since you can't be sure you've found the smallest or the largest value unless you've looked at everything. 

You can also try finding the min/max/avg in your MongoDB query using the [$group] (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator so you won't have to do any of that work in Python.